# How do I use mod_rewrite to redirect from folder to another folder?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If the user types this url:

http://www.mydomain.com/username/admin

I want the user to get

http://www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php

Without the url changing in the browser address field. How does the mod_rewrite rule looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have recently renamed the page foo.html to bar.html and now want to provide the old URL for backward compatibility. However, we want that users of the old URL even not recognize that the pages was renamed - that is, we don't want the address to change in their browser.

We rewrite the old URL to the new one internally via the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/foo\.html$  /bar.html [PT]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried this but I must be doing something wrong. This is my rule. ^/admin$  http://www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php [PT] Maybe I should explain what I need this for. I want a user to login at mydomain.com/user/admin and redirect to mydomain/admin where all the php files are.